# Google Apps versus web hosting emails

Tags: email, email-server, g-suite

Our organization is running on Google Apps with 180 users at 5USD/user/month. Only 30 are active users while the rest are teachers who don't use much email, hence it gets very expensive. We are thinking of:

1) Create emails from cPanel of the hosting, all users access emails from desktop clients. Is this too naive for a business use?

2) Deploy an in-house mail server, and backup the emails. Would there be too much headache in maintaining this option for a person, or should it be outsourced?

Comment: It's pretty clear what you're asking, but it's unclear how we could help you make this decision -- you need to evaluate your organization's needs and make a decision based on them. There are a lot of factors to consider. You've named a few, but others, like retraining staff and your admin-team's time managing in-house mail) are things only you can really evaluate/judge.  Do take note of Drew's answer below though -- that might be your best bet (no real "changes" for the company, but the price tag goes away!)

Answer (score 2):

You have access to the free version of Google Apps if you're a nonprofit.

http://www.google.com.au/nonprofits/products/index.html#tab0#tab4

> Reduce your IT costs and help staff and volunteers work together more
>   effectively.
>
> Google Apps for Nonprofits offers your organization the flexibility
>   and cost-effectiveness of cloud computing, and the ability to do
>   real-time collaboration.
>
> Get the job done with Google Apps for Nonprofits:
>
> - Work better with colleagues through online collaboration Store
> - Store documents in the cloud: 30GB of storage across Gmail and Google Drive
> - Stay connected from anywhere; securely access data anywhere
> - Get things done faster by automating processes
> - 24/7 support; no hardware, no updates
> - **Free version of Google Apps for Nonprofits**

Comment: Thanks Drew, unfortunately our organization is registered outside of the US, thus is not entitled for this.

Comment: @Khairul Given that the URL provided is Google.com.**au**, have you checked?

Answer (score -2):

Many aspects depend on the host you choose.

There are hosts that do a perfect job on spam, with no bandwidth limitations and 99.9% uptime guaranteed. Such a host is certainly reliable enough for use in an organisation.

So there is no simple answer, as you need to look at several hosts and choose a good one.

You must be ready to pay for the service. A 30 $ a year host will not do it, but a 150 $ a year will be good.

Comment: How the hell can you say unequivocally that certain price points will be OK and certain ones won't be based on the vague information given?